# How to generate HTML file in Jmeter using GUI alone?

Tags: maven, jmeter

I want to generate HTML output for Jmeter test using GUI steps.

`jmeter -n -t sometest.jmx -l abc.csv -e -o outputhtml`

I want to include the step of generating html output just like simple `Simple Data Writer` listener in GUI.

I am using maven's plugin for jmeter and I can't specify html output in it. If I could put that step in the test then it can be easily automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 2.2.0, html generation is built-in:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Just add this in **configuration** element:

```
 <generateReports>true</generateReports>
```

Here is an example of a pom:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ubikloadpack.jmeter</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-generate-reports</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<description>Check that report generation works</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>
                <testFilesIncluded>
                    <testFilesIncluded>**/*.jmx</testFilesIncluded>
                </testFilesIncluded>
                <generateReports>true</generateReports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configure</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>performance test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate [JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) via Maven you need to

1. [Override JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for dashboard generation (i.e. switch reporting to `csv` format), example POM configuration would look like:

   ```
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>csv</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>
   <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
   ```
2. Generate the dashboard at the end of JMeter test execution via [Maven Exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) like

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>verify</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>exec</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <executable>java</executable>
           <arguments>
               <argument>-jar</argument>
               <argument>${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter-3.2.jar</argument>
               <argument>-g</argument>
               <argument>${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/${maven.build.timestamp}-example.jtl</argument>
               <argument>-o</argument>
               <argument>${basedir}/target/dashboard</argument>
           </arguments>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```